# prevent brute force attacks on the discount codes

Tags: magento2, security, discount

Is there a way to prevent brute force attacks on the discount code input eg limit the number of discount codes a customer can enter a day?

Comment: If it's enough to rate the limit per IP, then you can set up a rule in your Web Application Firewall so that each IP can access the checkout/cart/couponPost URL for example 10 times in 24 hours. Or even /checkout/cart but you might be careful with this so that you won't block customers from actually really buying things.